# Obtaining element attributes within a custom directive used within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

This is driving me a little bit crazy. I need to read the src of an image within a custom attribute:

```
app.directive('imgTransform', function () {
    return {
        retrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(elem.attr('ng-src'));
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine when used like so:

```
<img ng-src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/technics' alt="" img-transform="" />
```

However, it does not work inside `ng-repeat`:

```
<p ng-repeat='image in images'>
    <img ng-src='{{image}}' alt="" img-transform="" />
</p>
```

The value returned is `{{image}}`. How do I get the actual value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `attrs`:

```
console.log(attrs.ngSrc);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6SuWD/

The reason for this could be that `ng-repeat` uses the original DOM as template and recreates it for each iteration. For some (obscure to me) reason, you are reading the attribute of the template. This explanation could be very wrong though...

However, since Angular gives you the API to access the attributes, it would be safer to go with it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to watch for changes in this attribute using `$observe` since `ng-repeat` interpolates the values of `ng-src`. See [this reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24compile.directive.Attributes).

Answer (score 0):

LukaszBachman is correct. When you pass interpolated values to a directive, the interpolation hasn't fired yet when the directive is in its linking phase.

If you were to do console.log(attrs); - you would clearly see that there is an actual value on ngSrc, when looking in the browser console. However, since interpolation hasn't kicked in yet you dont have access to it.

This would get you the actual value of ngSrc:

```
myApp.directive('imgTransform', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('ngSrc', function (val) {
                console.log(val);
            });
        }
    }
});
```